# How to remove all data from a Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I started using a code that using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) realtime database. I implemented it to my solution. Connection and control was perfect, so I used it for the production environment.

After a while I was doing upgrade and I need remove all data again - but wait, there are no delete buttons in [console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) anymore at highest root level and only allowed in one selected item at once:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/{{project_name}}/database/data
```

In last update shown only this message and no steps what next:

> Read-only & non-realtime mode activated to improve browser performance
>   Select a key with fewer records to edit or view in realtime

Q how can I remove all data at once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase : Read-only & non-realtime mode activated to improve browser performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651204/firebase-read-only-non-realtime-mode-activated-to-improve-browser-performanc)

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate as the question is very similar to another question, just phrased differently. The other part of the answer, is that it would take literally one line of code ( Swift: *rootRef.setValue(nil)* ) to delete the database, assuming you authenticate as an admin.

Comment: @Jay it is not duplicate because - # this has right title question for issue # this describe exactly fast simple solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### **Why missing Firebase remove button ?**

Alvin from [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) :

> Record or node has too much data, which makes the data viewer switch to a read-only/non real time mode to increase the browser's performance.

---

### Remove all data from Firebase from command line

Firebase documentation show [Removing Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data) - just they don't show how remove all data.

For remove all data you can use [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) command - which remove whole [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) output on that node level

```
curl -X DELETE "https://{{project_id}}.firebaseio.com/.json"
```

so you can do this on every generated "[URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) node in console" by adding JSON extension

```
https://{{project_id}}.firebaseio.com/{{path}}/{{path}}/{{path}}/.json
```

Comment: @AlecRust it should work uri auth "https://{{name}}:{{password}}@{{project_id}}.firebaseio.com"

Answer (score 71):

You can manually create a JSON file that contains a single empty entry and import it, which will remove all existing entries.

Comment: Thanks. Worth an uptick?

Comment: super..:-) fastest way to clear the database..thanks

Comment: Haha. NIce. The Firebase guys forgot to keep a feature to manually delete database objects. Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is wondering, this works even for DB with high memory, for which the DELETE API fails stating too much data to be updated in one go.

Answer (score 36):

A simple way to remove all data from a firebase database is to use the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/).

Once the CLI is setted up you just need to use this command and your data will be removed :

```
firebase database:remove /
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer IMO. Using curl / rest for this when there is the firebase CLI tool seems cumbersome and inefficient.

Comment: Project with multiple database instances can remove all data by specifying specific instance like so:
`firebase --instance abcdef-r4566-45rty database:remove /`

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 1: console**
From your project, click on the `x` button at the top level of the database.

[image]

then click `delete`

[image]

**Solution 2: Programmatic**

whatever the language you are using , call something like:

```
database.set('/', null)
```

**Solution 3: Firebase CLI**
from your project folder (you already installed the firebase-tools) write the following in the terminal then hit `Enter` :

```
database:remove /
```

[image: firebase CLI remove all data]

**N.B:**

> Kindly consider to backup your data first.

Comment: FYI, Solution 1 (delete from the Forge), only works if you have a small enough database so that it can show the real-time view.

Comment: CLI did the job very well

Answer (score 5):

I used

```
curl -X DELETE "https://<prject name>.firebaseio.com/.json?auth=<Firebase Database secret>"
```

This deletes the database also with the data which is blocked from firebase UI. Hope this helps. Thank you

FYI :

```
Your get Web API key is in https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<database name>/settings/serviceaccounts/databasesecrets
```

else you can go to 
Project overview settings >> project settings >> Service Accounts >> Database Secrets

Also I am wanted to comment it on the comments section but due to lack of stackoverflow point I am writing it as answer

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically you can implement a method, that puts an empty set of data on the main root of database - specifically you can insert a null.

In my Android project it looks like this:

```
void removeDataFromDatabase(){
    DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    root.setValue(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new JSON file with content as {}.
Go to firebase console click on the 3 dots on right, click on import JSON, choose the newly created JSON file and it will delete all data from the firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

This code helps to remove one by one of your object in firebase realtime database.
by path name object removes all children.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("yourReferance").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    data.getRef().removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successfully remove", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            .....
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

sloved :

```
public void removeDataFromFirebaseDatabae(){
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getRefrence().child("what you will remove").addChildEventListener(new onChildListener(){
@override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dp,String str){
for(DataSnapshot dx : dp.getChildren()){
dx.getRef().removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new onSuccessListener<Void>(){
@override
public void onSuccess(Void pvoid){
Toast.makeText(this,"remove success",5000).show();
}});
}}});
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and create a minimal example with enough relevant context added so a normal programmer could understand what you did and how it solved the problem

Comment: حكيني عربي طارق مافهمت قصدك،هادا كود كامل