# How do I delete all nodes from my firebase realtime database in the console?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I want to delete all the nodes from my root directory as shown in the picture.

[image]

There's no delete button in the console, how do I delete them?

There's supposed to be a trash icon near the node, but it's not showing.

Comment: Try to use the mouse hover on top of `0` and a trash icon will appear, right?

Comment: That icon is not appearing

Comment: Just click or hover on the parent node your database uri, a cross ❌ icon or trash ️ icon will appear just click on that

Comment: No matter how many times I hover, or click the nodes , no icon appears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase console switched to read-only mode, since there's too much data for it to handle.

To delete a node, you can:

- run a `curl` request in a terminal window as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182390
- import an empty JSON file into the path you want to delete.
- use the API to delete the value from the path.
- Navigate to each of the child nodes, and delete those one by one, until you've either deleted them all, or the console switches back to realtime mode.

Answer (score 1):

**See
It appears on hover - just hover on that and then click on trash button**
[image]

**So after importing JSON**

[image]

Comment: Yes, it was showing for me before too, when my database was empty, but after I imported a JSON file into the database, it's not showing anymore. Maybe its a bug

Comment: check this after importing json

Comment: try to reload your page or check your internet connection