# Firebase Real-time Database File size

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

What is the minimum size of Real-time Database JSON in Firebase? Because when we import large JSON, it switches to the offline mode saying "**Read-only & non-realtime mode activated to improve browser performance Select a key with fewer records to edit or view in realtime**".

I searched [Firebase : Read-only & non-realtime mode activated to improve browser performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651204/firebase-read-only-non-realtime-mode-activated-to-improve-browser-performanc) and some other relevant sites. Nowhere I found the maximum limit size of file for the real-time database.

I know, it is very obvious, the more small JSON file we put, the more real-time we are. Please don't comment saying "use small size for the real-time database". I want to know the maximum file size for the real-time database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size is intentionally not documented. Finding it should not be your goal.

Note that only the console switches to read-only mode, the SDKs will continue to interact with the database as usual.

That said: if your clients are listening to the same level of data that is triggering read-only mode in the console, they are likely going to see suboptimal performance. If that is the case, consider a data model that requires the client to monitor less data at once.