# Firebase Realtime Database in console not working?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

When I try to delete or edit a node in my realtime database, I always get the info that I have to select a key with lesser elements to change something, else it is in read-only modus.

But when I click a low level node, nothing happens. So I actually can change nothing in my DB from console :(

A week ago I didn't see this warning and everything works great!
Any idea how I can get back to working version?

[image]

I also think the german translation is not very good, because it tells me that I should activate another mode. In English it says, that the mode got activated.

Comment: You're mixing three things here: 1) your database console switched to read-only mode, which happens when you have a certain amount of data under it. 2) the warning is badly translated. Please file a [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for that. 3) the database console doesn't handle clicks correctly anymore. I already reported that internally last week, so will add your report to it.

Comment: @puf well thanks for your comment i just needed some confirmation to feel better ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 5/24/17:**
  Problem resolved.  Works now.

It seems the ability to click on a child node and promote it to be the top element of the tree is broken.  Doesn't work for me either, even on a small database that is not in *Read-only & non-realtime mode*.  I'm almost sure it was working a day or two ago.

I'm seeing the failure when using Chrome.  Just tried Internet Explorer.  Its works there.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with IE. Very funny that a google product is not working with their own browser but with others :)

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing three things here:

1. Your [database console switched to read-only mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651204/firebase-read-only-non-realtime-mode-activated-to-improve-browser-performanc), which happens when you have a certain amount of data under it.
2. The warning is badly translated. Please [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for that.
3. The database console doesn't handle clicks correctly anymore. I already reported that internally last week, and added your report to it. This bug has been fixed internally and will go into production by May 23.

Comment: Thanks for the info ☺️

Comment: i tried it today, and it works like a charm ;-) thanks again