# Bug with fIrebase database web viewer

Tags: firebase, web, browser, firebase-realtime-database

I can not open any nodes via firebase database web viewer. I check several browsers, each ones have the problem. Maybe anyone know how to fix it?
Problem started 1-3 weeks ago. It worked fine earlier.

Video with problem: **https://console.firebase.google.com/**

Comment: Have you looked in the console (the browser console) to see if there is any errors?

Comment: If by "open" you mean the ability to click on a location and have it become the top node in the tree, that feature is broken with Google Chrome browsers but works with IE.  See this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102225/4815718

Comment: @Chris no errors in console