# Firebase deactivate non-realtime mode

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I am getting this warning message at firebase console:

```
Read-only & non-realtime mode activated to improve browser performance 
Select a key with fewer records to edit or view in realtime
```

How can I activate back the real-time mode? This is getting out of hand as I could not delete any node right now.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

By right the last 3 attributes are auto expanded in real time mode. Currently they are collapsed by default. Also, I could not delete the entire 'accounts' node in this case. If it is in the real time mode, I could do so.

Comment: When you follow the instructions and select a key with fewer records, are the normal editing capabilities for that node not enabled?  If your database is very large, you may have to go down a number of levels to find a node that is small enough.

Comment: @BobSnyder Sorry but I do not get what does 'select a key with fewer records to edit' mean. Let's say I got 'accounts' node. Under that node, I got many records for account. For each account record, I am only storing the account details. However, some of the account ID are used in 'receipts' node. So can I just simply select any account record and activate back the real-time mode?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38660496/4815718

Comment: Oops.  I see you left a comment on that answer a few hours ago.

Comment: If you click on `password` (the text, not the +) doesn't the display update to promote the `password` node to the top with editing of that node re-enabled?

Comment: @BobSnyder nope, it just redirect me to another page with only the node for the Ks8mW... In this case. Is there any way to activate the real time mode back in a way such as I can directly select on the Ks8mW that node and delete from there, rather than select the sub child under certain node, get redirected then delete from there. Because right now, I can't simply delete the entire node by clicking on the delete button beside 'accounts'

Comment: It's difficult to picture the behavior you are seeing.  It doesn't seem to match what I see with a large DB and console running in Chrome.  As the linked answer in my previous comment explains, realtime mode is only enabled when the selected node is small enough to not overwhelm the browser with data.  If a node is so large that realtime mode is not enabled, you will need to delete the node some other way, either from code or using the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/): `firebase database:remove [options] <path>`

Comment: @BobSnyder I see I see but is there any way to delete the entire node (Eg. accounts node with around 200 account record underneath) directly from firebase console if the real time mode is deactivated? I realized that once I populated more than 200 records, the real time mode will just get deactivated..

Comment: No, you cannot edit or delete data from the console when it is in non-realtime mode.

Comment: @BobSnyder So there is no way to switch it back to real time mode? Does deleting some nodes to reduce the dataset helps?