# Firebase : Read-only & non-realtime mode activated, How to add child node on console

Tags: swift, firebase, mobile, firebase-realtime-database

Right now, my Firebase only has read mode activated as seen by the warning message below:

[image]

I need to add a child node to somewhere with a lot of child nodes or just edit the information to create a new feature. However I don't want to do it programmatically as I have to change a lot of things in how I read the data, is there a way to add a child node for somewhere with a lot of child nodes using the console?

Comment: Have you seen this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651204/firebase-read-only-non-realtime-mode-activated-to-improve-browser-performanc

Comment: yeah, i have, was the method I had to use before, im thinking of having making a more efficient querying page that doesnt require me to write code to do queries and then run it on the app to see it in my console

Comment: you can open target node in new tab then all operations of that node will bee realtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](https://medium.com/@justintulk/editing-data-in-firebase-when-blocked-by-read-only-non-realtime-mode-1ce103f178e5) has the key.

Basically, just change the URL up top (near the "Go" button) to point to the node you want to add. After you press Go, you'll have a node waiting for you to be edited.