# Firebase not adding realtime data

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have around 3000 entities (key-value) pairs added in firebase db for realtime. 
Now I am trying to add more values from my flutter app, but its not adding(not showing). It was working fine with less number of values in db. Why is this happening with bulk data? What has to be solution?[image]

Comment: Is it not adding it via flutter, or are you talking via the web interface?

Comment: Can you share the code and the response of the API?

Comment: Its just that I do not see in web browser. Code is working fine when node is small

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

When there are more than a certain number of child nodes, or a certain amount of data, under a location, the Firebase console will stop showing updates in realtime. There is no way to change this behavior, aside from reducing the amount of data or number of child nodes, until the console switches to realtime mode again.

Note: this does not affect the clients/servers that are connected to the same location through the API. They will still be getting all updates in realtime.

Also see:

- [Firebase : Read-only & non-realtime mode activated to improve browser performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651204/firebase-read-only-non-realtime-mode-activated-to-improve-browser-performanc)

Comment: Yes, I tried to get update in app in realtime and I am able to fetch values. Its just browser that freezes fpr realtime. Thanks

Comment: In same scenario I can see if i add 1 entry at firebase, it gets upload but if i tries to add multiple entries after a period of 2 seconds(when data is bulk already) , its not uploading. Why is so? Will that data be ever uploaded?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Can you explain step by step how to reproduce the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: In one of the node which has around 3k entities already, I have location update method in app from where I am making request to add a new entity and updating that after a lapse of 5 secs for around 20 minutes, but its not adding neither updating in db. It was working fine when had less values. What can be solution here?

Comment: I changed rules playground to "set", it allowed to add data now. It was set as "read" automatically. What can be don to avoid this.

Comment: The non-realtime mode of the console, does not in any way affect API calls to the database. If you're having a problem posting updates to the API, I'd recommend opening a new question for that, with the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which we can reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

if you are NOT using FirebaseAuth then update your rules like // Not Safe

[image: Warning anyone on the internet can steal your Data.]

if you are Using FirebaseAuth then update your rules like // Safe

[image]

Comment: These rules has to be same for realtime and firestore? I am using firebaseAuth